How to stop yasnippet from triggering multiple times on same instance
I am having trouble with yasnippet triggering multiple times. If I type $times$ it will trigger and change to $\times$ but then everytime I move my cursor through $\times$ it will trigger again.
So if my cursor is at the t in $\times$ and I hit M-f to go to end of word it will trigger again and I end up with $\times$. I was wondering if there is a way to stop this from retriggering. Maybe there is a condition so that key "times" triggers but "\times" does not?
